# Custom php.ini files are considered as bad, why ? What problems does appear when using custom php.ini files in root or in sub folders of root?

Tags: php

I have researched on php.ini files and finally got that custom php.ini files that are placed inside the directories when one need, are problematic and can make unexpected errors. Can anyone tell why custom php.ini files are not good to use on the server ?

Comment: Depends, what do you mean by custom? php.ini files downloaded from the internet or adjusting the existing php.ini files?  Adjusting the php.ini is not bad, but downloading custom ones from the internet is bad.

Comment: By custom we mean per directory php.ini files that you manually create and add into the server.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that you need php to behave differently on a per-directory basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so bad to use customized php.ini files. Of course, it is true that some major problems and security issues may be created in this case, but if you leave the sensitive sections as default, there won't be any security problems at all. Also, you can improve the security of a web application by editing the php.ini customs. For example, you can set the http_only flag on default php sessions.

Comment: Then why using .user.ini file. As i have read elsewhere that .user.ini files are introduce to prevent using custom php.ini files directory wise.

Comment: You have a simple php.ini file and you'll be able to set some properties in it, what do you mean by user.ini files?

Comment: i mean php.ini file

Comment: What do you want to do that you need specific php.ini file per directory?

Comment: Well, but be aware that there is no need to have special php.ini file for each directory. in some cases you need to change the defaults and basics that you can use .htaccess files instead. for example, defining a RewriteRule or editing some php.ini files without having access to the php.ini file.